# How to automate Bing Map by using Selenium Webdriver with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bing-maps

How to automate Bing map using Selenium Webdriver with C#, now pushpins could not identify on Bing map, whole canvas gets selected.

Comment: What exactly you wanted]

Answer (score 0):

Selenium followed and used DOM model and the canvas's child elements wont visible in DOM. So as per my thinking is not possible.

Read folllowing blog:

**http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/automated-testing-of-html5-canvas/**